# Cant connect database in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: database, azure

Error 10060 when trying to connect to Azure database in Visual Studio 2019.
I tried disabling Antivirus, Removing Firewall IP Settings and adding IP address again, still no connection

Here are the steps I used

Open Server explorer

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lz6S.jpg)

Tools > Add Connection > Fill in Server and Database name > Click OK

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh6O5.png)

Error Message Generated

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkNfF.png)

Azure Account used to access Database

[Azure Account Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQhrM.png)

Comment: Server name should be like `tcp:pa**sqlserver.database.windows.net,1433`, Data source choose `Microsoft SQL Server(SqlClient)`. And suggest you set firewall, allow all ip ,`0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255` for test.

Comment: can you show us any screenshots or the whole error message? Can you try to connect Azure SQL database with other tools such as SSMS? Did you open the port 1433?

Comment: Hi @Amos Matthew, please add the IP '208.30.120.67'  to you Azure SQL database firewall. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the error message, this is caused by the Azure SQL database firewall.

Please add the IP '208.30.120.67' in the error message to the database firewall, it will be solved.

Comment: Thank you for your positive response. I did enter my laptop IP address to the Firewall Rules and it still did not work. I was not able to access my database in SQL Server Management Studio until I registered my Server. That's when I gained access to my database to enter tables.

Comment: Today, I finally was able to access my database and enter tables. I also contacted Microsoft to report this issue and they have not made contact as yet to help out with this issue. It is possible they may have worked behind the scenes to facilitate progress. Thanks again!!